# Limit on SQL Insert into Snowflake from Jitterbit

Tags: sql-insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jitterbit

I've been trying to insert data into Snowflake from Dynamics CRM 365 via Jitterbit. There seems to be an issue with inserting more than 250 records at a time, as in, it fails when the number of records is greater than that, but works fine at 250. It seems to be an issue with Snowflake insert rather than Jitterbit, so I just wanted to see if anyone knew if this was an issue and if there was a way around it. I've tried resizing the warehouse to Large (usually xs) but didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Snowflake has a [Limits on Query Text Size](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits.html) but 1MB of text is a lot. What exact error message are you receiving? Have you tried to see [query history](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html#viewing-query-details-and-results) and check if the INSERT query is correct?

Comment: I didn't know I could see the query history, that's really useful , thankyou. Sorry, a bit new to snowflake. It looks like I'm hitting that limit with SQL Insert then as it is trying to put all the data to insert into a sql statement (I could see it had successfully done this when records amounted to 250, but the fields and values were blank in the statement when it failed). There is an option in Jitterbit to change the approach from SQL insert to Stage File, which I couldn't work out before but will revisit. Thanks again.